# PHP if today is Saturday or Sunday

Tags: php

I'm trying what should be a simple IF statement to show content if the day of the week is Saturday or Sunday. This statement always returns true.

```
<?php 
 if(date('D') == ('Sat' || 'Sun')) { 
      echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday.";
    } else {
      echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
    }
?>
```

I also tried: `(Sat || Sun)` and `(Saturday || Sunday)`

Any ideas here?

date('D') = `Sun`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The issue is, you have to check the condition individually.

Try this:

```
<?php
if(date('D') == 'Sat' || date('D') == 'Sun') { 
  echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday.";
} else {
  echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
}
?>
```

**Explanation:**

`date()` function with `'D'` parameter will return the day like `Sat`, `Sun` etc

`Output` : Today is Saturday or Sunday.

[Working code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ef03c965b91c69939a87acf09fdc210c576cfa2)

[date() parameters list](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation.

Comment: Thanks, happy coding :)

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `date('N')` where Sat = 6 and Sun = 7

```
<?php
if(date('N') > 5) { 
    echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday.";
} else {
    echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can simply do it using in_array() function

```
<?php
if(in_array(date('D'),['Sat','Sun'])) {
   echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday.";
} else {
   echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
}
```

Comment: For me, this is the cleanest answer. Clear whats happening, short and makes use for PHP's functions.

Answer (score 2):

Give it as 2 different conditions

```
<?php
if((date('D') == ('Sat')) ||(date('D') == 'Sun'))) { 
   echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday.";
    } else {
      echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use php's `date()` with `l` as the parameter which gives you the full day of the week name. Examples are Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Applying this to your scenario,

```
<?php
$dayOfWeek = date('l');
if($dayOfWeek  == 'Saturday' || $dayOfWeek == 'Sunday') { 
  echo "Today is Saturday or Sunday";
} else {
  echo "Today is not Saturday or Sunday.";
}
?>
```